# Oracle 10 SQL: FULL JOIN through Cross Reference Table

Tags: sql, join

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/24637/1

I have three tables, (better details/data shown in sqlfiddle link), one replacing another, and a cross reference table in between. One of the fields in each of the table uses the cross reference (version), and another one of the fields in each of the tables is the same (changeID).

I need a query that when passed a list of new_version + new_changeType, along with the equivalent original_version + old_changeType (if there is an old version equivalent) PLUS any old changeIDs that were 'missed' in the conversion of data.

```
                        TABLES (fields on the same line are equivalent)

OLD_table         |   XREF_table         |  NEW_Table
original_version  |   original_version   |
changeID          |                      |  changeID
OLD_changeType    |                      |
                  |   new_version        |  new_version  
                  |                      |  NEW_changeType


                         DATA

111,1,CT1       |     111,AAA            |  AAA,1,ONE
111,2,CT2       |     222,BBB            |  AAA,2,TWO
222,1,CT1       |     333,DDD            |  BBB,1,ONE
222,2,CT2       |                        |  BBB,2,TWO
222,3,CT3       |                        |  CCC,1,ONE
333,1,CT1       |                        |
444,1,CT1       |                        |
```

If passed the following list, the result set should look like so. (order doesnt matter)

```
 AAA,BBB,CCC

 | NEW_VERSION | NEW_CHANGE_TYPE| ORIGINAL_VERSION | CHANGEID | OLD_CHANGE_TYPE |
 |-------------|----------------|------------------|----------|-----------------|
 |         AAA |            ONE |              111 |        1 |             CT1 |
 |         AAA |            TWO |              111 |        2 |             CT2 |
 |         BBB |            ONE |              222 |        1 |             CT1 |
 |         BBB |            TWO |              222 |        2 |             CT2 |
 |         CCC |            ONE |           (null) |   (null) |          (null) |
 |      (null) |         (null) |              222 |        3 |             CT3 |
```

I'm having trouble getting ALL the data required. I've played with the following query, however I seem to either 1) miss a row or 2) get additional rows not matching the requirements.

The following queries I've played with are as follows.

```
select 
a.new_version, 
a.Change_type, 
c.original_version,
c.changeID,
c.OLD_Change_type
from NEW_TABLE a
LEFT OUTER JOIN XREF_TABLE b on a.new_version = b.new_version
FULL OUTER JOIN OLD_TABLE c on 
 b.original_version = c.original_version and a.changeID = c.changeID
where (b.new_version in ('AAA','BBB','CCC') or b.new_version is null);

select 
a.new_version, 
a.Change_type, 
c.original_version,
c.changeID,
c.OLD_Change_type
from NEW_TABLE a
 FULL JOIN XREF_TABLE b on a.new_version = b.new_version
 FULL JOIN OLD_TABLE c on 
 b.original_version = c.original_version and a.changeID = c.changeID
where (a.new_version in ('AAA','BBB','CCC'));
```

The first returns one 'extra' row with the 333,DDD data, which is not specified from the input.
The seconds returns one less row (with the changeID from the old table "missed" from when this data was converted over.

Any thoughts or suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: In your example there is an entry in XREF_table for each original_version in OLD_table. Is this guaranteed to be so?

Comment: No there won't be an entry in the XREF table to all entries in the OLD_table, however the only rows that we care about from the OLD_table, will have an entry (so in a general sense you can take that as a simple yes).

Comment: In your result list, shouldn't new_version be BBB for the last line? Yes, there is no entry in new_table, but xref_table holds the new_version, too, which is BBB for 222.

Comment: Either way would work, although you're correct in that would make the result set more of a complete picture (and easier to read/use) - we're looking for a big picture, as well as being able to provide a list of rows that were missed in the conversion of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First inner join old_table and xref_table, as you are not interested in any old_table entries without an xref_table entry. Then full outer join new_table. In your WHERE clause be aware that new_table.new_version can be null, so use coalesce to use xref_table.new_version in this case to limit your results to AAA, BBB and CCC. That's all.

```
select 
  coalesce(n.new_version, x.new_version) as new_version,
  n.change_type, 
  o.original_version,
  o.changeid,
  o.old_change_type
from old_table o 
inner join xref_table x 
  on x.original_version = o.original_version
full outer join new_table n 
  on n.new_version = x.new_version 
  and n.changeid = o.changeid
where coalesce(n.new_version, x.new_version) in ('AAA','BBB','CCC')
order by 1,2,3,4,5
;
```

Here is your fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/24637/11.

BTW: Better never use random aliases like a, b and c that don't indicate what table is meant. That makes the query harder to understand. Use the table's first letter(s) or an acronym instead.

Comment: Did not know about coalesce prior to your answer - I can see that being useful. Thanks!